# jasmine mock second method

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I am trying to do the following thing in Jasmine but not sure if it is possible :

I Got a service object with 2 methods, A and B.
Method A calls method B (B is in fact a $http call which I do not want to do during my test : I want to mock it).

In my BeforeEach section I do this : 
`spyOn(Serviceinstance, 'B').and.callFake(function(){
     return true;
      });`

in my Test :

```
var result = Serviceinstance.A();
expect(result).toBeTrue();
```

Of course, the real code of B returns false.
My problem is that my test always fails. the function provided in the spy is never called by method A. 
On the other hand, If I call B like this :

```
var result = Serviceinstance.B();
```

Then the function of the spy is called, and my test passes.

So should I modify my instance like this :

```
Serviceinstance.B = function(){return true;}
```

because Jasmine cannot mock a "second" level of the call stack ? (seems totally unlikely to me)

I am definitively missing something....

Comment: I know the question may seem dumb but this is really the behavior I am having. I've read the jasmine doc but do not understand what's going on so any pointer is welcome (C# backgound, so Mocking is ussually no big deal :) )

Answer (score 1):

This is a code that works:

```
describe('Service test suite', function() {
    it('should return true', function() {
        var Serviceinstance = new Service();
        spyOn(Serviceinstance, 'B').and.callFake(function() {
            return true;
        });
        expect(Serviceinstance.A()).toBe(true);
    })
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ronapelbaum/9moLhhbr/